# Discrete math Big O notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question that states: "Let k be a positive integer.  Show that $1^k + 2^k + ... + n^k$ is O($n^{k+1}$)".

Below is my answer, I'm a little confused about the equalities, I've seen people use them loosely in their answers.

**Answer:**  We see that $1^k + 2^k + ... + n^k$ < $n^k + n^k + ... + n^k$ = $nn^k$ = $n^{k+1}$, when $n > 1$.  Thus $1^k + 2^k + ... + n^k$ is O($n^{k+1}$), taking k = 1 and C = 1 as witnesses.

Also, since k is the usual variable for witness.  Can I change k to l, in order to not confuse this with the k constant in the problem statement.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes. It can be confusing to use $k$ for two different things in two consecutive sentences. Preumably the  phrase "$k=1$" comes from another sentence defining $O$. So change that $k$ to $k'$ and change "$k=1$" to "$k'=1$".

Comment: Thank you!  Also, are my equalities and witnesses stated correctly for a consistent solution?

Comment: Yes.  Couldn't be more succinct or clearer.

Comment: Thank you!  Have a good evening!